# What exactly should I pass as ID of the desired status to statuses/retweet/:id

Tags: twitter

Question regarding Twitter API and this method https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid.

Can someone please explain me what is `id` parameter means in `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/:id.json` method?

> The numerical ID of the desired status.

is not clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this URL

https://twitter.com/edent/status/671673463673876480

The `ID` is the long number at the end.  You'll find it in the `id_str` of any status you access via the API.